# Insertion sort in C not iterating over the array correctly

Tags: c, arrays, insertion-sort

I am trying to implement insertion sort in C, but it is not stepping through the array correctly. I'm attempting to implement the pseudocode from Cormen's Algorithms book.

It looks like the first element is being ignored but all the others are being stepped over just fine, so I imagine it's a problem with my indices. However, even with gdb and some carful looking, I'm missing it.

If you guys wouldn't mind taking a quick look at this code, I'd be grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insertion_sort(int *array);

int main(void)
{
    /* 6 is a constant length of the array */
    /* could be replaced with a variable, etc in real-scenario */
    int array[6] = {5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3};
    insertion_sort(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

void insertion_sort(int *array)
{
    int j, i, key;
    for (j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
        key = array[j];
        i = j - 1;
        while (i > 0  && array[i] > key) {
            array[i+1] = array[i];
            i -= 1;
        }
        array[i+1] = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array already has six members. Where would you like to insert the new member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your while loop. It should be like this:

```
void insertion_sort(int *array)
{
    int j, i, key;
    for (j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
        key = array[j];
        i = j - 1;
        while (i >= 0  && array[i] > key) {
            array[i+1] = array[i];
            i -= 1;
        }
        array[i+1] = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Cormen's book just has `i > 0`. Then again, the example does use 1-indexed arrays (and j = 2, etc). Thanks.